# How to check if library is used or not in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, libraries

I have an old iOS project that evolved over time in which were added many librairies.
Some of them are not longer used today.
My question is, how can I check in the iOS project which library is used or not ?

Comment: I don't know whether there is any way to find that programmatically. My way of checking this would be removing suspected frameworks one by one and compiling each time after the removal. So if any error comes, the framework is needed, else not needed. But if there is so many libraries in your project, it would be tedious.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do that. But what you can do is try removing the path of the suspected frameworks(If they all are at same path, I'd suggest you to place them separately)from the `Library Search Paths`and look for errors(if any).

Hope this helps.